# optimize sql query that consumes time with unions and not in

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization, mysql-5.7

I am working with mysql and running the following query in order to add new rows that don't exist in  both table 1 and table 2 .

```
 INSERT INTO table2 (a,"2" )
 select a  from table1 where b ="1"  
 and a NOT IN  ( 
 select a from table1 where b ="2" 
 UNION  
 select a from table2 where b ="2"  ) 
 UNION  
 select a  from table2 where b ="1"   
 And a NOT IN ( 
 Select a from table2 where b ="2" 
 UNION 
 select a from table1 where b ="2"  
 );
```

example:

```
table1      table2
----------  ---------- 
| a | b  |  | a | b  | 
-----+----  -----+----
| t1 | 2 |  | t3 | 5 | 
| t2 | 3 |  | t2 | 6 | 
----------  | t7 | 4 | 
            ----------
```

I would like to add a row to table2 if it does not exist already in any of the tables example (t1,5) should be added but not (t1,2).

the query works but consumes a lot of time since i have a big database. is there a way to optimize it ? maybe replace UNION and NOT IN ,with joins ?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? What version? Update the tags...

Comment: Looks like a case for a possible `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: I am using MySQL Server 5.7

Comment: explain better with details what you are trying to achieve. provide raw data set and expected data set after this insert completed. and what is your  `LIKE "1"` means?

Comment: Get rid of this awfully confusing expression:  `b = "1" like "1"`.  (Or explain what its intent is.)  Then, I'll give you some optimization tips.

Comment: sorry i messed it up when i edited it , it is only b="1"